# Redirecting www.domain.bio to domain.bio for my app on Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: next.js, digital-ocean

I recently deployed my next.js app to Digital Ocean, it's working perfectly on my domain.bio, however, it wasn't working on [www.domain.bio](http://www.domain.bio). So what I did was, I inserted domain.bio as a domain on App Platform domains under my app, then inserted *.domain.bio, which looks like this now:
[image]

The problem is, now domain.bio and [www.domain.bio](http://www.domain.bio) are 2 separate websites and logging in one isn't affecting the other (normally).

I tried to insert CNAME www on my digital ocean domains section, but it kept throwing 421 misdirected request (cloudflare) when I visited [www.domain.bio](http://www.domain.bio).
Currently, my domain DNS looks like this:
[image]

What can I do to redirect [www.domain.bio](http://www.domain.bio) to domain.bio?

Comment: No clue if you still need this, but I believe Digitalocean added a feature to support this in the configuration of the App in the App platform. Go to your app, then navigate to "Settings" and look for "HTTP Routes Redirect". I have not tested this yet, but it looks like this is the way to do it.